# How do I evaluate clustering for mixed data accuracy, like K-Prototype>

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining

There are a lot of validity index for clustering, but just for numeric data. what about clustering for mixed data (numeric and categorical) ?

Answer (score 1):

The same way, mostly.

You obviously can't use inertia, but anything that is distance based (and doesn't use the cluster mean) will work with the distance you used for clustering. E.g., Silhouette.

Unfortunately, the distance functions for such data are not very trustworthy in my opinion. So good luck, and triple check all results before using them, as you may have non-meaningful results that only look good when condensed to this single score number.